# How to stop (and not to skip) ply-parser at parse-error?

Tags: python, ply

How can I stop the parser if an error detected?

The example

```
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)
```

shows only a skip but I need a stop. How to archive?

Comment: What is `t`? There might me a method for that...

Answer (score 1):

You can raise an exception when you encounter an error in the lexer. For example:

```
class LexerError(Exception): pass


def t_error(t):
    raise LexerError("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value)
```